# Multi step user registration form drupal 6

Tags: 6, forms, users

How to do Multi step user registration form in drupal 6 ?

I am having an idea of doing multistep process using custom form.

**But i am bit confusing while doing the same case with "user registration".**

For example :

Let us consider i am having 10 fields and separating it with three forms like 4+4+2.

**Now when i complete the first form and click next button where should i need to save the values of current form. I used $form['storage']. But it didn't helps.**

Could anyone please clear me this or provide me an easy tutorial for **"multistep user regsistration".**

Any help will be thankful and grateful..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

This blog post may help you: [Multistep registration form in Drupal 6](http://shvetsgroup.com/blog/multistep-registration-form-drupal%C2%A06)